# Use ExecuteQuery<T>() on an SQLiteCommand

Tags: linq, sqlite, linqpad

## Problem

In LINQPad 4, when I try to run the following code:

```
void Main()
{
    using (var conn = new SQLiteConnection(@"C:\linqToSqlite"))
    {
        var query = new SQLiteCommand(conn);
        query.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM MyTable";
        var result = query.ExecuteQuery<MyTable>();
    }
}
```

I receive the following error:

> 'System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand' does not contain a definition for 'ExecuteQuery' and no extension method 'ExecuteQuery' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand' could be found (press F4 to add a using directive or assembly reference)

## What I have tried

Additional References:

```
System.Data.Linq.dll
System.Data.SQLite.dll
System.Data.SQLite.Linq.dll
```

Additional Namespace Imports:

```
System.Data.Linq
System.Data.SQLite
System.Data.SQLite.Linq // Cannot add this, cleanup removes it.
```

[I've also found documentation](http://rbdocumentation.com/html/8d794541-d5b7-c66a-4446-beecccae7ee9.htm#!), which talks about using the `SQLiteCommand.ExecuteQuery` method. That's the only place I have seen the command mentioned.

Comment: If I remember it clearly, I think SQLLiteCommand doesn't support such a method. Maybe you should consider using Linq's SqlLiteDataContent's ExecuteQuery<T>()

Comment: @ProgrammingFan In what assembly do we find the `SqlLiteDataContext` and its `ExecuteQuery<T>()` method?

Answer (score 3):

Don't think this feature is built-in. Whenever I need to do execute a direct sql query against a sqlite database, I add a Nuget reference to Dapper and add the namespace Dapper. This then allows me to do something like.

```
   string query = "Select * from MyTable" ;
   var results = this.Connection.Query<MyTable>(query).ToList();
```

or

```
   using (var conn = new SQLiteConnection(@"C:\linqToSqlite"))
   {
      string query = "Select * from MyTable" ;
      var results = conn.Query<MyTable>(query).ToList();
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

From your given document I find you can consider using it by referring **RebornBuddy.exe Version: 1.0.233.0 (1.0.233).**

This is an image:

[image]

And the SQLLite.dll's ExecuteQuery() just uses no "generic type". So it's ONLY used in a common ado.net. And if you insist using that in LINQ (and if that's implemented). Maybe you can use something like "SqlLiteDataContext's ExecuteQuery".

For more about SqlLiteDataContext's ExecuteQuery, please see this in detailled info:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb361109(v=vs.110).aspx